# How to delete selected files from the command line

Tags: list, shell, command-line, find, delete-file

I have a shell command that I run to scan my server and list all files with the name *temp_file_14* in the */home* directory tree as follows:

```
find /home . -name "temp_file_14" -exec ls -lh {} \;
```

I would like to change this command to have it physically delete the "found" files instead of listing them. Can someone help me with what the command should look like to perform a delete task instead of a list task?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
find . -name "temp_file_14" -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Or this one:

```
find . -type f -name "temp_file_14" -exec rm -f {} \;
```